select() returns 10038, Windows Socket error
I'm trying to make p2p application with login function. This application will send commands to server by console input and i'm tried to implement this but it finished on 10038 error which means that i'm doing operation on a nonsocket. This error is returned by select() function. I don't have ideas how to resolve this so I wrote on Stack Overflow, thanks for any help.
Here is fragment of a client code:
...
while (true) {
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_SET(sock, &readfds);
    FD_SET(0, &readfds);

    timeout.tv_sec = 1;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    int activity = select(0, &readfds, nullptr, nullptr, &timeout);
    if (activity == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        cerr << "Select failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        break;
    }

    if (FD_ISSET(sock, &readfds)) {
        memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
        int bytesReceived = recv(sock, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);

        if (bytesReceived > 0) {
            cout << buffer << endl;
        } else if (bytesReceived == 0) {
            cout << "Connection closed by server" << endl;
            break;
        } else {
            cerr << "Failed to receive data: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (FD_ISSET(0, &readfds)) {
        getline(cin, response);

        if (send(sock, response.c_str(), response.size(), 0) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            cerr << "Failed to send data: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
            break;
        }

        response = "";
    }
}
...


What is the exact text of the error message, and what line of your code is causing it.

Could you post the code that creates the socket before select()? You can get this error 10038 if the socket isn't initialized correctly and I wonder if the program doesn't call bind() correctly.

Sure. Here is a full code @GandhiGandhi. The message is a "Select failed: 10038" and it caused by int activity = select()... line @PresidentJamesK.Polk

On Windows, using socket 0 to represent stdin will not work.  Unlike on other platforms, sockets on Windows are not file descriptors, and stdin cannot be acted on using socket APIs in this manner. That is why select() is complaining about something that is not a valid socket. It only works with real sockets.
See: How can I detect if there is input waiting on stdin on windows?, in which the OP tried to do the same thing you attempted.
You will have to handle your socket I/O and console I/O separately.  For instance, you can call WaitForSingleObject() with GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE) when select() times out.  Or, you can move your console input into a different thread.
